# Trigerring event remotely from other device

Tags: php, ajax, web

I want to update data on my website (which is projected on a screen), when someone clicks button in my web administration.

Basically, when someone creates a new post on my web administration, I want to put this post on a page which is projected on a screen. But I don't want to e.g. update the screen every five seconds.

Comment: Hi, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a [on topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and how to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need is Socket.io. https://socket.io/ This can help communicate clients in real time.